# Tomcat APR connector and POODLE

Tags: tomcat, apr, poodle-attack

I have a couple of production servers running Tomcat 7.0 with an APR+SSL connector and because of the recent POODLE attack I was asked to disable SSLv3 completely in some of these servers. I dig through the [Tomcat Connectors](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support) documentation and according to it, setting `SSLProtocol` to `TLSv1` (instead of `all` should be sufficient to disable SSLv3 and enforce TLSv1.

The problem is that `TLSv1` seems to enable TLS but does not make the server refuse SSLv3. I tested this using `openssl s_client -connect -ssl3` and I verified that plain-old SSLv3 connections can still be accepted, so I was wondering if this is a bug in Tomcat or if there is something else that I need to set to disabled SSLv3 completely.

**UPDATE:** I disabled APR for now and reverted to using a NIO connector with `sslProtocol="TLS"` and that works fine. The problem seems to be specifically affecting APR. For reference, this is my new connector configuration:

```
<Connector port="443" 
  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
  SSLEnabled="true"
  maxThreads="500" 
  scheme="https" 
  secure="true"
  clientAuth="false"
  keystoreFile="/etc/keys/***.ks"
  keystorePass="****"
  sslProtocol = "TLS"
  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the ability to disable SSL completely when using the APR connector with TLS is still a work in progress. Check this link for more information: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53952#c30, specifically Comment #37.

The good news is that it'll be fixed in the next release of the Tomcat and Tomcat Native. See comment #39:

```
Fixed in tcnative-trunk in r1632593 and tcnative-1.1.x in r1632595. 
Will be in tcnative 1.1.32.
```

and Comment #40:

```
Fixed in Tomcat-trunk in r1632604. Will be in Tomcat 8.0.15.
Fixed in Tomcat 7 in r1632606. Will be in Tomcat 7.0.57.
```

Comment: Is there a release date for tcnative 1.1.32? Last time (Heartbleed) it took Apache almost two weeks to release a version with the fixed version of OpenSSL...

Comment: Things should go more quickly this time around.

Comment: If you have the opportunity to rebuild OpenSSL, you can recompile with `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3` set and the OpenSSL library will compile without support for that protocol. There is no runtime option I know of (e.g. environment variable) that can disable SSLv3 in OpenSSL.